# Decision trees With branching Factor?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, data-mining, decision-trees, data-science-model

How to construct a Binary Tree from a decision tree with branching factor greater than 2 (b>2)?

Answer (score 1):

I think the following issue is related to your question:
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/12187/are-decision-trees-almost-always-binary-trees

Let's say you have for each node, 3 children with three different conditions:

```
n1 -> cond a -> n2
   -> cond b -> n3
   -> cond c -> n4
```

For binary trees, however, each node holds only one condition and it is evaluated to either True or False, thus meaning you go to the right or the left child. For making the previous simple tree binary, you just need to chain the conditions of a node in the binary tree. For example:

```
n1 -> cond a -> n2
   -> not cond a -> _n2 -> cond b -> n3
                        -> not cond b -> _n3 -> cond c -> n4
```

Comment: This paper shows the equivalence of binary and ternary decision trees in case you're looking for something more technical.
https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/PL00009169